# Edit the width of bars using pd.DataFrame.plot()

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, bar-chart

I am making a stacked bar plot using:

```
DataFrame.plot(kind='bar',stacked=True)
```

I want to control width of bars so that the bars are connected to each other like a histogram.

*I've looked through the documentation but to no avail - any suggestions? Is it possible to do it this way?*

Comment: You *want* to pass in width=1 (to bar) but plot won't let you... :s

Comment: Strange. The align keyword behaves as the opposite of mpl and the log keyword is also weird. @Osmond, i would workaround it by using: ax.bar(df.index.values, df.values)

Answer (score 106, accepted):

For anyone coming across this question:

Since pandas 0.14, plotting with bars has a 'width' command:
https://github.com/pydata/pandas/pull/6644

The example above can now be solved simply by using

```
df.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True, width=1)
```

See [`pandas.DataFrame.plot.bar`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.bar.html) or [`pandas.DataFrame.plot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html) with `kind='bar'`.

When changing the width of the bars, it might also be appropriate to change the figure size by specifying the `figsize=` parameter.

Answer (score 17):

If think you have to "postprocess" the barplot with matplotlib as pandas internally sets the width of the bars.

The rectangles which form the bars are in container objects.
So you have to iterate through these containers and set the width of the rectangles individually:

```
In [208]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((6, 5)) * 10,               
                        index=list('abcdef'), columns=list('ABCDE'))

In [209]: df
Out[209]: 
     A    B    C    D    E
a  4.2  6.7  1.0  7.1  1.4
b  1.3  9.5  5.1  7.3  5.6
c  8.9  5.0  5.0  6.7  3.8
d  5.5  0.5  2.4  8.4  6.4
e  0.3  1.4  4.8  1.7  9.3
f  3.3  0.2  6.9  8.0  6.1

In [210]: ax = df.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True, align='center')

In [211]: for container in ax.containers:
              plt.setp(container, width=1)
   .....:         

In [212]: x0, x1 = ax.get_xlim()

In [213]: ax.set_xlim(x0 -0.5, x1 + 0.25)
Out[213]: (-0.5, 6.5)

In [214]: plt.tight_layout()
```

[image: stacked_bar.png]

Comment: nice answer. I didn't realize 'postprocessing' was an option

Comment: I am using df.plot to overplot additional bars on a preexisting bar plot.  @bmu, your method does not work for me because it changes all the old plot objects, in addition to the new ones. How to change the width of just the bars newly created by df.plot()?

Comment: @ChristopherBarrington-Leigh Maybe you could start the iteration over the container objects at a later index (at the number of your previous container objects), however an example would be better. I think you should better ask this in a separate question.

Answer (score 2):

## a matplotlib solution

modify the `width` parameter in `ax.bar` as you like
[image]

**code**

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(15).reshape(5, 3), columns=list('ABC'))

print(df)

fig, axs = plt.subplots(1, 2)

ax = axs[0]
xs = np.arange(df.shape[1])
ys = np.zeros(xs.shape)
for ind in df.index:
    ax.bar(xs, df.loc[ind, :], label=ind, bottom=ys, width=.4)
    ys += df.loc[ind, :]
plt.setp(ax, xticks=xs, xticklabels=list(df))
ax.legend(title='rows')
ax.set_xlabel('columns')

ax = axs[1]
xs = np.arange(df.shape[0])
ys = np.zeros(xs.shape)
for col in list(df):
    ax.bar(xs, df.loc[:, col], label=col, bottom=ys, width=.4)
    ys += df.loc[:, col]
plt.setp(ax, xticks=xs, xticklabels=df.index.to_numpy().tolist())
ax.legend(title='columns')
ax.set_xlabel('rows')

plt.show()
```

**df=**

```
    A   B   C
0   0   1   2
1   3   4   5
2   6   7   8
3   9  10  11
4  12  13  14
```

Answer (score 0):

"I want to control the width of bars so that the bars are connected to each other like a histogram."

A better option for the same is to use **sns.displot()**

Sample code:

```
emp = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/arora123/Data/master/emp-data.csv")

sns.displot(emp, x='Department', hue='Gender', multiple='stack',  
             height=8, aspect=1.7);
```

[image]

Comment: Note that: the code will produce the same plot but not the same aesthetics. I've done some customization to reduce the chart junk.